# Узнать длину текста

Tags: javascript, canvas

Помогите найти решение. Работаю в canvas, нужно вывести в текст и если он длинее ширины моего окна нужно перевести на новую строку. Как найти длину текста в пикселях чтоб сравнить её с шириной моего окна или есть другой вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var text = "Some text..."
var info = context.measureText(text);
console.log(info);
```

```html
<canvas width=128 height=128></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо подходит, а есть ли ещё методы?

Comment: Эм.. А почему нужны ещё?

Comment: этот подходит, интересуюсь для расширения знаний.

Comment: Если проблема решена, надо принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.